# Scripting layer for Android - LibGDX

Tags: javascript, android, jar, rhino, sl4a

I've been writing a full game engine on top of LibGDX for sometime now and had written almost every single game object in Javascript (I created a composite based game object system). For the JS interpretation, I used the Rhino engine which on my ubuntu system, works phenomenally well, however when I tried to run it on Android, I was not able to get it to compile at all and from what I HAD read, it's because Google didn't use a standard Java implementation that supported Rhino, but now I'm seeing the support with the SL4A project, however I was looking for a simple Rhino jar file that was compatible with Android but after looking through the downloads, all I found were APK files that did not appear to have the library and from what I have read, the APK is suppose to be a template project, but how can I use it with my existing code without a jar package? Maybe I'm totally missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [SL4A Rhino repository](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/?r=835425b4ac473f2a2acfe9c4c2b92343f31b36ec#hg/rhino) has all the necessary add-ons (among them rhino1_7R2-dex.jar) to get Rhino running on Android.

Comment: nice..thanks guys. I may have to resurrect the project now :)